# Timetracking employees

Tags: work-time

Does time tracking employees (arriving time, leaving time, breaks) and paying them according to their time spent at work will work ? They spend a lot of time in breaks or leaving work for some time.

Tasks tracking per employee would be nice but the environment is not built to support the implementation of such change.

Comment: you need a location here - where I live it is mandatory to provide a certain amount of paid breaks, so your plan to reduce pay by the amount of breaks taken might contravene labour law. Honestly a better approach is to have the right mix of people and work that everyone loves to do it and doesn't look for things to do instead of working while they are on site.

Comment: Location, Industry/work being performed, how you're currently handling pay, scheduling, and breaks, and whether you're trying to save money or reduce time away from work (or however you're defining "will work") should be included in your question. Please [edit] your question to add clarification.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what type of job you are talking about.  Jobs with a substantial amount of thinking/problem solving/creative activities are really hard to track with time-tracking - a person can have their crazy good idea in the shower or while taking a walk - so the time away from the desk is as important as the time at it.  Thus the general arrangement of salary work, where the number of hours spent at it is intentionally rather vague, it's more about what gets done in a larger unit of time (week, month, etc) and also ability to be responsive to the team when needed.

Alternately - there still are per-hour type jobs where you have to be on site to reasonably be considered doing the job - retail, food service, construction, physical security - all come to mind as this type of work.  There's still high variation between great performance and mediocre performance, but there is still some connection between time spent on the job site and amount of work accomplished.

So - IMO - it depends on the job you're trying to get done.